# Sharepoint word document stuck on downloading while opening

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, word-automation

In my document library I am not a able to open a specific document from my Sharepoint site.
When I click on the link it open in MS Word launching window, and launching window gets stuck with the message "Downloading 'Document Url'" 
I am able to download this document and then it opens perfectly from local file system. 
I tried to open previous versions of the document from it's version history. But not latest version of this document.
Other document in the library works as expected. Can anyone help me with this as this applies to a single document only so there might not be any issue with the IE settings.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try disabling automatically detecting LAN settings in IE - Options - Tab "Connections" and in dialog under "LAN settings" button.